# Check Input text if empty based upon radio button selected

Tags: javascript

I have two radiobuttons in a group on my page. Based upon radiobutton selected i want to generate an alert.

```
var d=GetVal();

function GetVal()
{
var a = null;
var f = document.forms[0];
var e = f.elements["radiogroup"];

for (var i=0; i < e.length; i++)
{
if (e[i].checked)
{
a = e[i].value;
break;
}
}
return a;
}
```

At the time of form validation, It is always returning only first radiobutton value when iam reading it in if else loop.

```
if (!checkRadio("form","radiogroup")) 
{
alert("none of the option was selected"); 
return false;
}
//if one radio option was selected
else
{
if(d="firstradiovalue"){
alert("first radio selected");
return false;}
else{
if(d="secondradiovalue"){
alert("second radio Selected");
return false;}
}
}
```

At the time of form submission, even if i choose second option i only get alert - "first radio selected". Any help. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `==` not `=`:

```
if(d == "firstradiovalue"){
    alert("first radio selected");
```

The return value of the expression `d = "firstradiovalue"` is `d` itself, which is always true.

Comment: Right, that's why many programmers like to turn around the parts: `'firstradiovalue' = d` would result in an error, making debugging easier.

Comment: @Geert interesting inspection, never saw it this way! :)